How can I properly set up a before and after analysis to determine a correlation of voter turnout?
For my own understanding, I'm interested in analyzing whether or not an increase or decrease in the lobbying of a specific industry, in a wide variation of cities, had an increase or decrease in the voter turnout of a particular political party.
In order to properly analyze this, what statistics do I need to compile, and further, how/what procedure do I need to follow to either determine a correlation or be 95% confident in a deduction? This might seem vague but I'm asking for guidance on how I might proceed on this, since the information might come from hundreds of cities.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I don't know how to do that, I'm not a statistics expert, hence I'm asking for guidance. In other platforms, you're perfectly allowed to ask "soft-questions", but I saw no option for that tag here.

The first step is to clarify your question, because "increase" and "decrease" are relative terms. Relative to what? Measured in what way? Compared in what way (e.g., rates, totals, ratios, ...)? You need to consider how "lobbying" and "voter turnout" might be measured (e.g., money, manpower, ads; or totals, proportion of all voters, proportion of party voters, etc. for the second). Part of this step, too, is to consider how you might aggregate the increases or decreases across these cities. A clearer problem formulation will help us respond constructively.

@whuber Well, lobbying is a technically defined term wherein a representative or spokesperson for a party or special interest group confers with a political candidate to support specific legislation. So, the more times that happens, the more or less a certain outcome that happens, or otherwise, it is deemed the money spent and turnout are uncorrelated. This may be evaluated in the money a specific industry chooses, and is documented, to spend on lobbying, or, the number of meetings, or other yet-to-be-determined metrics. Likely though, spending would be considered.
